# smtp.gmail.com railo.runtime.exp.NativeException:javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:0

Tags: gmail, railo

This works on my ColdFusion server, but not on my Railo server:

```
<cfset subject = "xxx">
<cfmail usessl="yes" username="xxx@gmail.com" password="xxx" port="465" type="html" server="smtp.gmail.com" 
subject="#subject#"
from="xxx@gmail.com" to="xxx@gmail.com">
#subject#
</cfmail>
```

When I turn Spool enable off my Railo server, I get:

> smtp.gmail.com
>   railo.runtime.exp.NativeException:javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:0

At first, Google balked at a program trying to login as me in a different city, but I've told them it was me.
Under [unusual activity](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en), I have:

> You recognized all the unusual activity below as yours

And the Railo server is in the list.

Comment: C:\railo\lib\railo-server\context\logs\mail.log is empty except for the header.

Comment: Never got ssl to work. Use tls.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate certificate in your Railo server's keystore (if it does not use a recognized CA)?

Comment: Oh, it's saying "Application/device sign-in attempt (prevented)" and everything after "atte" is not being displayed on the page no matter how wide my screen is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Unlock-Gmail-For-A-New-Email-Program-Or-Service.htm

says to go to

[Allow a new application to access your account page at Google.](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Also this page:
http://www.placona.co.uk/132/vps/full-google-mail-smtp-power-for-your-domain/

said to use port 587 and usetls instead of usessl.